# access violation (c system exception code : c0000005 ) while accessing ccomptr pointer and application got crash

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, mfc

While accessing a computer I get an access violation error.
The error is not consistent and only reproducible while trying to access a huge data.
I have 2900 components and for each component I am calling a function. In this function I am accessing a ccompter, while doing this application gets crashed at random position like on 200, 210, 2500 etc. The position in not fixed when it crashes.

This issue is specific to the system with following configuration:
Window Server 2003 R2
Xeon CPU , 2.66 ghz
2 GB of RAM

here is my code

```
XGGraphicAttribute* pAttr = pExtraGraphicInfo->GetAttribute();
if(pAttr)
{
    DBAttributes* db_attributes = NULL;

    db_attributes = static_cast<DBAttributes*> (pAttr->GetDBAttributes());

    CComPtr<IEPGraphicData> pIEPGraphicData;

    if(db_attributes)
    {
        pIEPGraphicData = db_attributes->GetGraphicData(); // here my app got crashed 
    }

}


IEPGraphicData* DBAttributes::GetGraphicData () const
{
    return m_pIEPGraphicData;
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `db_attributes`?

Comment: Is the call going from one DLLL to another?

Comment: 1. m_pIEPGraphicData is a CComPtr<IEPGraphicData> and its assign to the pIEPGraphicData  that is also a type of CComPtr<IEPGraphicData>.  2. db_attributes is a DBAttributes class pointer. 3. the call doesn't goes to other dll call.

Comment: Why is the static_cast<> needed here - What type does pAttr->GetDBAttributes() actually return?

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities:

1. The object returned by GetGraphicData() might not support the IEPGraphicData interface. I would expect the smart pointer assignment to result in a null pointer though, rather than an access violation.
2. The db_attributes object has been deleted from underneath your feet.